# Can somebody explain me why "had gone"

Tags: past-tense

The last story I heard was that Alan Mc Gee (boss label) had tried to organise a come-back concert. After hearing about the plans, however, the band **had gone** to the studio and **burned** all the tapes they had ever recorded, then **demolished** everything in the studio. By the time Mc Gee got there, the studio was a smouldering ruin.

burned and demolished are past simple. Past perfect "had gone" expresses the intention (they have gone to burn and demolish)

Is it a possible explaination ?

Comment: I don't know the technical terminology, but no it's not about intention, it's about *time*. I think it's technically incorrect though. It would make sense to say "By the time he got there, it was a ruin. After hearing about the plans, the band *had gone*...". The idea here is that we're telling a story in the past tense, but now we need to say that something happened even *before* that. In other words, they had *already* gone to the studio. However in this case, they should have written "After hearing about the plans, the band *went* to the studio...".

Comment: I think the past perfect is used because it's describing an event in the past before another event in the past: before Alan McGee tried to organize the concert, the band **had already** gone to the studio.

Comment: But as tried is also past perfect we don't know what came first   and it is written after hearing about the plan  so it means that the band knew before going to the studio to destroy it